# Date format showing only current year

Tags: php, date

```
$ddd=`1 December, 2014`;
$from = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($ddd));
echo $from.
```

Returns `2015-12-01 00:00:00` instead of `2014-12-01 00:00:00`

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: backtick instead of quotes & a `.` after `echo` line? that's syntax error, isn't it?

Comment: try changing `$from.` to `$from;`

Comment: Also, the date does not fall into any valid date format accepted by `strtotime()`: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php , thus PHP blind guesses it.

Comment: $from="0";
if (isset($_POST['input_01'])) /* for example 1 December, 2014 */
{ 
$ddd=$_POST['input_01'];
echo $ddd.'<br/>';
$from = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($ddd));
echo $from.'<br/>';
}

Comment: Don't use punctuation mark, http://codepad.org/BCwn82qP

Comment: // please remove the comma // $ddd='1 December 2014';
$from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($ddd));
echo $from;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**strtotime** only understands a [specific set of formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). If your input is not in one of these formats, it will do its best to guess, but as you can see the results can vary.

try this :

```
 <?php
    $ddd = '1 December, 2014';
    $t = date_create_from_format("d M, Y",$ddd);
    $from = date_format($t,"Y-m-d 00:00:00");
    echo $from;
    
 ?>
```

Comment: *version note: since PHP 5.3*

Answer (score 2):

In [strtottime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) documentation, it says:

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
>   dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Therefore, you should convert the `$ddd` to an [acceptable date format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) before using `strtotime()`. Even better, if you have PHP 5.3+, you can use the [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) function:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!d F, Y', '1 December, 2014');
```

where `$date` is a `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this answer. It  works.

```
 $ddd='1 December 2014';
    $from = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($ddd));
    echo $from;
```

Comment: Are you suggesting removing all commas from `$ddd`?

Comment: Yes if you directly using strtotime() function. The date format should be "1 December 2014".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ddd='1 December 2014';
 $from = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($ddd));
 echo $from;
?>
```

[demo](http://codepad.org/OYEBsHfE) you should remove ',' from the date '1 December 2014'